# first week number to date prints previous year

Tags: python

I want follow code to print 2020-01-01 00:00:00 instead of 2019-12-30.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
d = '2020-00'
r = datetime.datetime.strptime(d + '-1', "%Y-%W-%w")
print(r)
2019-12-30 00:00:00
```

Comment: how does that make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks; got it.  Deleted my substandard comment.

Comment: Replace by `print('2020-01-01 00:00:00')`: what *is* your question, what do you want help for?

Answer (score 1):

2020 started on a Wednesday. From this handy [Python `str[fp]time` reference](https://strftime.org/), `%W` stands for

> Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0.

while `%w` is

> Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday.

You passed the value `2020-00-1`, which corresponds to the 0th week's Monday, which was in fact 2019-12-30.

To make it result in 2020-01-01, do the following:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = "2020-00"
>>> r = datetime.datetime.strptime(d + "-3", "%Y-%W-%w")
>>> print(r)
2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: I need  "2020-01" to start with monday too. Only the first week of the year is problem.

Comment: @tompal18 `2020-01-1` yields `2020-01-06 00:00:00`, which was a Monday. I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.